# Redshift SQL Join on Date columns with date ranges on tables with million records

Tags: sql, date, join, amazon-redshift

Given two tables A(with 50 million records) and B(with 6000 records).

No partitions.

Table A: SortKey (start_date,end_date)

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-06-01 |
| 66 | 2020-05-01 | 2020-07-31 |
| 88 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-11-31 |

Table B: sortkey(rec_date)

| rec_date |
| --- |
| 2019-02-01 |
| 2019-03-01 |
| 2020-07-01 |
| 2021-05-15 |

Result Table:

| id | start_date | end_date | rec_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-06-01 | 2019-02-01 |
| 11 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-06-01 | 2019-03-01 |
| 66 | 2020-05-01 | 2020-07-31 | 2020-07-01 |
| 88 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-11-31 | 2021-05-15 |

**The current code is** -

```
select a.id, 
       a.start_date, 
       a.end_date, 
       b.rec_date
from tableA a 
     join tableB b
on b.rec_date between a.start_date and a.end_date;
```

**Query Plan:**
XN Nested Loop DS_BCAST_INNER (cost=0.00..5981078476.08 rows=24749818904 width=40)
->  XN Seq Scan on TableA a (cost=0.00..649222.88 rows=64922288 width=36)
->  XN Seq Scan on TableB b (cost=0.00..34.31 rows=3431 width=4)

This code takes a lot of time to run. Looking for any better approach.

Comment: What is the sort key ? is there any partition?if yes how partitions are defined? also provide the query plan for this query

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. PS Still no [mre] or research reflected.

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research before considering posting. That includes basics of SQL optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Also your DBMS manual re all those. [ask] [Help]

Comment: "`between a.start_date and a.start_date`"--? Cut & paste & run from your draft question & when that shows the problem behaviour then publish it.